# How to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN QuerySet in Django - Many to One

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I got two models: Image(filename, uploaded_at) and Annotation (author, quality,... fk Image).

An Image can have multiple Annotations, and an Annotation belong to one image.

I'd like to build a queryset that fetch all annotations (including the relation to the image so I can display image fields as well) that meet some criteria.

All fine until here, but I'd like to display also the images that have no annotations created (left outer join), and not sure how could I proceed to do this?

To clarify I am trying to get fetch the data so I can build a table like this:

```
Image name, Image date, Annotation author, Annotation Quality
image 1   , 2019      , john             , high
image 2   , 2019      , doe              , high
image 3   , 2019      , null             , null
image 4   , 2014      , doe              , high
```

Maybe I'm using wrong approach, I'm using Annotation as main model, but then I don't seem to have a way to display the images that don't have Annotation, which kind of makes sense as there is no Annotation.
This is what I'm doing:

```
Annotation.objects.select_related('image').filter(Q(image__isnull=True)
 | Q(other condition))
```

However, if I use Image as main model, the relation is many Annotations to one image so I can't use select_related, and I'm not sure prefetch_related works for what I need. I don't know how to get the data properly. I tried this:

```
Image.objects.prefetch_related('annotations').filter(Q(annotations__isnull=True) | Q(other condition))
```

The prefetch_related doesn't seem to make any difference to the query, plus I'd like to have the Annotation data in flat/the same row (ie. row 1: image 1, annotation 1; row 2: image1, annotation 2, etc.) instead of having to do image.**annotation_set**... as that wouldn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an outer join, it has to be a left join, as you correctly assumed. So you'll have to start from the `Image` model. To get a flat representation rather than nested `Annotation` objects, use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), which returns a queryset of dictionaries (rather than model objects):

```
queryset_of_dictionaries = (Image.objects
    .filter(Q(annotations__isnull=True) | Q(other condition))
    .values('name', 'date', 'annotations__author', 'annotations__quality',
            # etc. – you have to enumerate all fields you need
    )
    # you'll probably want the rows in a particular order
    .order_by(
        # a field list like in values()
    )
)

# accessing the rows
for dic in queryset_of_dictionaries:
    print(f'Image name: {dic["name"]}, quality: {dic["annotations__quality"]}')
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed! Thank you sir!